# react-native reseting TextInput after ClearTextOnFocus

Tags: react-native

I am building a form in React-Native and have set ClearTextOnFocus to true as it is easier to handle dynamic formating for editing.

I am trying to add a reset function by setting all local state to the redux store, but if the user has not typed anything in a selected TextInput, the local state has not changed, and react native does not re-render the TextInput; leaving it blank.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I can unclear the TextInput or force React to re-render. Code is a work in progress, but here are the relevant bits.

Thanks

```
class GoalScreen extends Component {

  componentWillMount = () => this.setPropsToState();

  onReset = () => {
    this.setPropsToState();
  }

  onChange = text => this.setState({ [text.field]: text.input });

  setPropsToState = () => {
    const { name } = this.props.goal;
    this.setState({ name });
  };


  render() {
    const { name } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.screenContainer}>

        <Text style={styles.text}> Name </Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="a brand new bag"
              keyboardType="default"
              autoCorrect={false}
              style={styles.inputField}
              clearTextOnFocus
              onChangeText={text => this.onChange({ input: text, field: 'rate' })}
              value={name}
              />
          </View>

  }
}
```

Comment: I think your onChangeText prop may be an inline function, and if so you should consider re-writing it (see https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578)

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not using Redux, and my use case might be a bit different than yours, but I thought my solution might still be relevant here, if only to confirm that (after hours of wrangling with this) it appears that passing true to the clearTextOnFocus prop prevents further updates to a TextInput component.

I tried every conceivable workaround (like setNativeProps(), forceUpdate()) but nothing worked, so I ended up having to basically write my own logic for clearing and resetting the input text.

This component should 1) clear input text on focus and then 2) reset it to its previous value if the user hasn't pressed a key:

```
class ResettableInput extends Component {
  state = {
    Current: this.props.value,
    Previous: ""
  };

  KeyPressed = false;

  //cache current input value for later revert if necessary, and clear input
  onFocus = () => {
    this.setState({ Previous: this.state.Current, Current: "" });
  };

  //record whether key was pressed so input value can be reverted if necessary
  onKeyPress = () => {
    this.KeyPressed = true;
  };

  onChangeText = text => {
    this.setState({ Current: text });
  };

  //if no key was pressed, revert input to previous value
  onBlur = () => {
    if (!this.KeyPressed) {
      this.setState({ Current: this.state.Previous, Previous: "" });
    }
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
        value={this.state.Current}
        onBlur={this.onBlur}
        onFocus={this.onFocus}
        onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
      />
    );
  };
}
```